# unable to get data though model function code igniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, model

I have created one new function in a existing controller, in which I am accessing a model's function which has a query to get the list.

I have loaded the model in controller. This model function works with other function but not working for new created function.

```
class Cart extends CI_Controller 
{
    function Cart()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->mdl_common->checkUserSession();
        $this->load->model('mdl_friend_web');
        $this->load->model('api/mdl_friend','mdl_friend_api');
        $this->load->model('mdl_cart_web');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }
```

//works for this function

```
    function ajax_get_cart_list($offset = 0) 
    {
        is_ajax();
        $this->load->model('mdl_cart_web');

        $limit = PER_PAGE;

        $s_data = $_POST;

        $carts = $this->mdl_cart_web->get_cart_list($limit,$offset,$s_data)->result_array();
        $totalRows = $this->mdl_cart_web->get_total_cart_product($s_data)->num_rows();

        $data = $this->mdl_common->pagination_data('cart/get_cart_list/',$totalRows,$limit,'show_data');
        $data['carts'] = $carts;
        $data['total_cart'] = $totalRows;

        $html = $this->load->view('cart/ajax_cart_list',$data,true);
        echo $html;
    }
```

//not working for this

```
    function calculate_distance()
    {


        $limit = '';

        $delivery = 0;

        $previousName = '';
        $count = 0;
        $oneShop = '0';
        is_ajax();
       // $this->load->model('mdl_cart_web');
        $lat1 = $_POST['lat1'];
        $long1 = $_POST['long1'];
      //  $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        $carts = $this->mdl_cart_web->get_cart_list($limit,0,'')->result_array();

        $response = array();
        $data['carts'] = $carts;
        foreach($data['carts'] as $row) {

            echo $row['store_latitude'];

        }

    }
```

model

```
<?php
class Mdl_cart_web extends CI_Model
{
/*=================================================================================
                                Get cart list   
==================================================================================*/

    function get_cart_list($limit,$offset,$data)
    {
        $this->db->select('c.*,p.*,s.name as store_name,s.latitude as store_latitude,s.longitude as store_longitude,count(r.product_id) as review , IFNULL(AVG(r.star),0) as avg_star,i.*',false);
        $this->db->join('p_product as p','c.product_id = p.product_id','left');
        $this->db->join('p_product_image as i','c.product_id = i.product_id','left');
        $this->db->join('p_product_review as r','c.product_id = r.product_id','left');
        $this->db->join('p_store as s','s.store_id = p.store_id','left');
        $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);       
        $this->db->where('c.user_id',$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
        $this->db->group_by('c.cart_id');
        $this->db->from('p_cart as c');


        return $this->db->get();
    }

?>
```

I am not able to get the array data.I can see blank alert.
What is going wrong here? Please help.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are writing your query not properly try this:

```
$this->db->select('c.*,p.*,s.name as store_name,s.latitude as store_latitude,s.longitude as store_longitude,count(r.product_id) as review , IFNULL(AVG(r.star),0) as avg_star,i.*',false);
$this->db->from('p_cart as c');
$this->db->join('p_product as p','c.product_id = p.product_id','left');
$this->db->join('p_product_image as i','c.product_id = i.product_id','left');
$this->db->join('p_product_review as r','c.product_id = r.product_id','left');
$this->db->join('p_store as s','s.store_id = p.store_id','left');
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);       
$this->db->where('c.user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
$this->db->group_by('c.cart_id');
return $this->db->get();
```

Comment: query works fine with other function, so there is no issue in query I think.

Answer (score 0):

As Above comment and after seeing your question that the model works fine for the one function and not for the other so I think that loading a model is what you have to look properly.

I see that in your not working function you have noticed some basic problems.

1. You have commented the model loading code after `is_ajax()`. `// $this->load->model('mdl_cart_web');` so first remove that comment and try again.
2. Send Correct and proper data to the model. Please Check this below line of code that is executing properly or not.

In Your Not working model.

```
$carts = $this->mdl_cart_web->get_cart_list($limit,0,'')->result_array();
```

In Your Working Model:

```
$carts = $this->mdl_cart_web->get_cart_list($limit,$offset,$s_data)->result_array();
```

And One thing I want if you are using the same model in more functions in the same controller then you should use `__construct()`

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct ();     
    $this->load->model('mdl_cart_web');              
}
```

By adding a model into the `__construct()` you can use it in the entire controller and all of the functions.

Comment: I have loaded model in _construct to use in whole controller also first I had locally loaded the model in that function but both the way its not working.

Comment: Have you removed the comment? or check the data passing to the model is correct or not @Sid

Comment: Yes removed the comment. I don't want any limit for query so I am passing limit as blank offset as 0 and data parameter is not used in query so it's blank.